# Why is WireGuard not in main?

Tags: official-repositories, wireguard

WireGuard is very, very popular and for good reason. Still, Ubuntu keeps it in universe and doesn't seem to have any interest in placing it front and center. Why? It's so strange, it's probably the coolest thing since SSH was introduced.

Comment: Whether or not a package should be in "main" seems like an appropriate discussion for http://discourse.ubuntu.com. Perhaps it's as simple as nobody has suggested it....

Comment: Does it being cool mean somebody is going to pay for Canonical to maintain it in `main`?

Comment: @muru: I would think somebody would be willing to pay for support for something as important as VPN, yes. But it has never in history been the case that Ubuntu is only for paying customers. There's lots of stuff in main that isn't particularly corporate in nature.

Comment: True, there's lots of stuff there - but either stuff that's included by default in the main desktop offerings, or stuff that companies are typically willing to pay for, like OpenVPN, Apache httpd, etc. Le new cool thing has to become part of either of those. I don't think there are that many big corporations rushing to adopt Wireguard yet, for all that random users like you and me really like it.

Comment: No, main is not only for desktops. It's just as much for servers. And Ubuntu didn't always even have paying customers. Ubuntu is not Microsoft.